# Firebase Analytics - permission issue

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have some permission issue in firebase analytics. When I go to Analytics => Events => Modify Events => choose android or iOS, I get error that "You do not have permission to access these settings" and when I click on "View more in Google Analytics" I am getting error that "Missing permissions - You do not have access to the account, property or view. Contact an Analytics administrator who has the Manage Users permission." Screenshot for both error attached. [Google Analytics Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtYAr.png) [Modify Event Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP87P.png). I have owner and admin access in both firebase and Google Analytics account.

This issue may be due to multiple firebase and google analytics account. But I don't know how can I check and fix this.

Comment: Same issue but cannot seem to figure out, will let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Same issue. Big number of users in company if that's an issue. Other services are allowed to modify.

Comment: Same problem. Any solution?

Comment: @Vingtoft I had the same problem you can create custom events through your code.
Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can't create custom events on Firebase console. Create through you code and customs events will appear in dashboard. Sometimes it takes time to reflect your data maybe 2 hours or less
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the user you want to have permission to edit/add the `Analytics => Events => Modify Events` in https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/ in the analytics project linked to Firebase. The user should be granted Editor access.